# How do I get the id of the beacon using Kontakt.io beacons?

Tags: ios, swift, kontakt.io

Currently I recognize beacons, as `CLBeacon`objects. Example:

```
CLBeacon (uuid:F7826DA6-4FA2-4E98-8024-BC5B71E0893E, major:57140, minor:4299, proximity:1 +/- 0.77m, rssi:-75)
```

But I need here the name of the beacon. I mean `b1A8`:

[image]

Is there any way to access it from code?

Now, I do it like this:

```
func beaconManager(_ manager: KTKBeaconManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: KTKBeaconRegion) {

    for beacon in beacons {

        //here need to have a name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iBeacon format itself doesn't allow for custom data to be included on the advertising packet, so Kontakt.io beacons have a custom [*scan response packet*](https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/201492522), which includes things like battery, firmware version, transmission power, and most importantly: unique ID (b1A8).

Because this isn't an iBeacon advertisement packet, you'll need to rely on Core Bluetooth instead of Core Location. If you're using their SDK, you can do so by using [KTKDevicesManager](http://kontaktio.github.io/kontakt-ios-sdk/Documentation/html/Classes/KTKDevicesManager.html), and [KTKNearbyDevice](http://kontaktio.github.io/kontakt-ios-sdk/Documentation/html/Classes/KTKNearbyDevice.html).

From their developer center:

```
extension ViewController: KTKDevicesManagerDelegate {
    func devicesManager(_ manager: KTKDevicesManager, didDiscover devices: [KTKNearbyDevice]?) {
        guard let nearbyDevices = devices else {
            return
        }

        for device in nearbyDevices {
            if let uniqueId = device.uniqueID {
                print("Detected a beacon \(uniqueId)")
            } else {
                print("Detected a beacon with an unknown Unique ID")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How we going to know which KTKNearbyDevice is belong to related CLBeacon device? There is no common property to match them.

Answer (score -1):

This is how i do it. I wish it would help.

```
var nearestBeacon: CLBeacon!


    func beaconManager(_ manager: KTKBeaconManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: KTKBeaconRegion)
    {
    let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.unknown }
        if (knownBeacons.count > 0) {
            nearestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] as CLBeacon
        }
        print(knownBeacons, "+")


        if nearestBeacon != nil {

            switch nearestBeacon!.minor.intValue {

            case 1:

                changeColorWithAnime(color: .blue, status: .show)

                logNearestBeacon(beacon: "Balcony")



                changeColorWithAnime(color: .orange, status: .hide)
                changeColorWithAnime(color: .yellow, status: .hide)
             //   print("Blue")

            case 2:

                changeColorWithAnime(color: .orange, status: .show)


                logNearestBeacon(beacon: "Bathroom")



                changeColorWithAnime(color: .blue, status: .hide)
                changeColorWithAnime(color: .yellow, status: .hide)
          //      print("Orange")

            case 3:

                changeColorWithAnime(color: .yellow, status: .show)
                logNearestBeacon(beacon: "Bedroom")



                changeColorWithAnime(color: .blue, status: .hide)
                changeColorWithAnime(color: .orange, status: .hide)

             //   print("Yellow")
            default:
                return

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything to help the OP as it doesn't reference getting the beacon's name or identifier.